# Opentelemetry - OTLP Exporter setup for jaeger

Tags: jaeger, open-telemetry-collector, otlp-grpc

while installing and running the OTLP collector in a my server,it throws the error,
Err: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"

My config setup:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
      grpc:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4317"
exporters:
   otlp:
      endpoint: "jaegersite.com:4317"
      tls:
        insecure: false
        insecure_skip_verify: true        
   debug:
       verbosity: detailed
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [debug,otlp]
```

Running jaeger in `jaegersite.com and exposed in 16686 port,`

Running Opentelemtry collector as image in the compose,
compose file,

```
otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml
    ports:
      - 1888:1888 # pprof extension
      - 8888:8888 # Prometheus metrics exposed by the Collector
      - 8889:8889 # Prometheus exporter metrics
      - 13133:13133 # health_check extension
      - 4317:4317 # OTLP gRPC receiver
      - 4318:4318 # OTLP http receiver
      - 55679:55679 # zpages extension
```

Also checked the above configuartion with TLS certicate for exporter as ,

```
tls:      
  cert_file: "./mycertificatepath/.pem file"
  key_file: "./mykeypath/.pem file"
```

same error came.

I want to setup a OTLP collector with Jaeger as a exporter endpoint which was hosted in another server and Instrumented application has been hosted in another server.Then how the receiver and exporter and port should be like and Overcome TLS issue.

Here is my jeager setup,

```
docker run -d --name jaeger \
  -p 5775:5775/udp \
  -p 6831:6831/udp \
  -p 6832:6832/udp \
  -p 5778:5778 \
  -p 16686:16686 \
  -p 14250:14250 \
  -p 14268:14268 \
  -p 14269:14269 \
  -p 4317:4317 \
  -p 4318:4318 \
  -p 9411:9411 \
  jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.52
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide full reproducible example, so answer may not be 100% correct and some additional adjustments may be needed.

You didn't expose how is jaeger configured, but it looks like you didn't configure TLS, so you have to export to Jaeger OTLP port without TLS:

```
exporters:
   otlp:
      endpoint: "jaegersite.com:<jaeger-otlp-port>"
      tls:
        insecure: true
```

BTW Jaeger port `16686` is for Jaeger UI. Jaeger has port `55680` for OTLP format usually (but again, you didn't show your Jaeger configuration, so it can be different port and/or TLS configuration in your case).

Comment: I added the Jaeger configuration above.Check and Correct me.Thank you in advance!!!.

Comment: @pradeep I gave you answer, so just determine which port of your jaeger setup is OTLP port (= read current jaeger documentation) and replace "<jaeger-otlp-port>" in my answer by that port.